# how to store log files in directory (directory name having current date) every day

Tags: java, date, logging, directory, logfile

The following code creates a directory with name as current date and stores the log files in that directory. But next the log files of the next days keep are also stored in same directory. I want create a new directory every day having the same name as current date and store new log file in it.

```
private static Date dir1 = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
private static Date dir = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
private static String baseDir1 = "/home/gaurav/flinklogs/";
private static String newDir1 = createDateBasedDirectory(baseDir1, dir1);

private static FileHandler fh1;

static {
    try {
        fh1 = new FileHandler(newDir1 + "/data.log", 0, 1, true);
    } catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
    // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter
    logger.addHandler(fh);

    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);

    // the following statement is used to log any messages
    logger.info(e.getMessage());
}

public static String createDateBasedDirectory(String baseDirectory, Date argDate) {
    String newDir = null;
    if (baseDirectory != null && argDate != null) {
        try {
            String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            String date = dateFormatter.format(argDate);

            // check if the directory exists:
            String todaysLogDir = baseDirectory + "\\" + date;

            Path todaysDirectoryPath = Paths.get(todaysLogDir);
            // and check if this Path exists
            if (Files.exists(todaysDirectoryPath)) {
                // if present, just return it in order to write (into) a log file there
                return todaysDirectoryPath.toUri().toString();
            } else {
                newDir = baseDirectory + date;
                new File(newDir).mkdir();
                return newDir.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return newDir;
}
```

Comment: You should probably take a look at log4j or logback. These frameworks can easily be configured to achieve log rotation as you described it

Comment: @Rea Sand Thanks but i have tried it...there are so many problems with log4j.properpties file and other thing... i want to do it this way only.. any solution with this??

Comment: Try [*Logback*](https://logback.qos.ch) a modern logging framework by the man who originally made *log4j*. The *Logback* project directly implements the [*slf4j*](https://www.slf4j.org) façade API.

Answer (score 2):

Your date-time handling could use some help.

First, you are using troublesome old date-time classes (`Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`)  that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. And you are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone (discussed further down below).

- `java.util.Date` is replaced by `java.time.Instant`
- `SimpleDateFormat` is replaced by `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

Your desired format of YYYY-MM-DD is defined by the ISO 8601 standard. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when generating/parsing strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

### `Instant`

> new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())

That code of yours is redundant. Simply calling `new Date()` has the same effect, capturing a count of the number of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Modern code replaces `Date` with `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

But we really do not need `Instant` for your Question. Use `LocalDate` instead.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone][2] explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or you might choose to always use UTC, as the people do running Stack Overflow. Notice how your daily reputation points roll-over, for example around 4 PM if on west coast US time.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### String

To generate a `String` in standard ISO 8601 format, simply call `LocalDate::toString`.

```
String output = today.toString() ;
```

## Logging framework

As other suggested, you should not use your valuable time re-inventing a logging framework to rollover folders daily. Any decent logging framework can do that for you.

In particular, I suggest you consider first using the [*slf4j*](https://www.slf4j.org/) façade API. In your code where you want to make send info to logs, make calls to *slf4j*. Behind *slf4j* sits any of many different logging frameworks. You can later switch out one logging framework for another without changing your app’s code.

If not already using a logging framework, adopt [*Logback*](https://logback.qos.ch/). The *Logback* project is a direct implementation of the *slf4j* API. So no need for an adapter.

Both *slf4j* and *Logback* were written by the same man who invented *log4j*. So he has much experience in this field.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you have declared all your variables as static and performing file handler assignment in static block as well.

```
static {

        try {

            fh1 = new FileHandler(newDir1 + "/data.log", 0, 1, true);

        } catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {

        }
    }
```

So, once your program starts it initialises everything and then next day there is no re-initialisation as the program is already running from previous day.
You need to reassign the file-handler with change of day.

Also, may I suggest having a look at log4j as you can easily configure it as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks, how do i reassign the file-handler with change of day

Comment: Try with a cron job that runs daily at midnight and reassigns the new handler.

Comment: Sorry will you elaborate it plz...how to use cron job

Comment: If you are not sure how cron jobs work, i would highly discourage you from writing your own logging framework. Please try to re-use existing frameworks as others suggested that will do this job for you already.

Comment: i have used log4j but there is problem in that when i run my jar file on server it is unable to find the log4j.properties file, thats why i am using this....

Comment: @Gaurav your log4j config should reside in `src/main/resources` to be picked up automatically by the framework. But you may (and probably have to) provide any other path when starting you application via `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` (or smth similar).

Comment: @Rea Sand suppose i have created a jar file of my application and i want to run it on server then where should i provide this -Dlog4j.configurationFile??

Comment: @Gaurav You should consider consulting the [official log4j documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) as it contains examples for the different usecases, including yours. For you to get started though: put your log4j configuration file at smth like `/etc/<your-service>` or `/usr/local/etc/<your-service>` and reference the config like so: `java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml -jar /path/to/your/jar`